# Angular 2+ Content Projection and Component property binding

Tags: angular, components, projection, angular2-ngcontent

I'm stuck on a hard stuff about Angular Content Projection.
I would like to project a component A into another one B and bind some properties on the component A.

For example,
I have a SwitchButton component (with several choices). I want this component to display either texts or images.

To do so, here is my SwitchButtonComponent (HTML):

```
<div class="container border rounded bg-white">
   <div class="row text-center">
      <div *ngFor="let it of items" class="col" style="cursor:pointer;">
         {{it}}
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I omitted the ts class, no need here, but of course it has an *items* property.
I use this component in another one like so:

```
<div>
   <switch-button [items]="['A','B','C']"></switch-button>
</div>
```

Well, this is the easy case. It works fine.

Now, I have a more complex object in items and I want to display an image.
It will give:

```
<div>
   <switch-button [items]="[{path:'./img1.png'},{path:'./img2.png'}]">
       <img-component></img-component>
   </switch-button>
</div>
```

The *img-component* is just a simple component rendering an image and having one property: the imgPath.

And in the SwitchButtonComponent:

```
<div class="container border rounded bg-white">
   <div class="row text-center">
      <div *ngFor="let it of items" class="col" style="cursor:pointer;">
         <ng-content></ng-content>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here you can see I can't bind the imgPath property of the projected component (img-component).

Do you have some ideas guys ?

Comment: I see an extra `{` on this line: `<switch-button [items]="[{path:'./img1.png'},{{path:'./img2.png'}]">`. Is this intentional?

Comment: Ah! Not at all, it's just a mistake of mine! I correct it right now.
Thanks :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know if this is possible using `ng-content`. I solved it using `<ng-container>` (if that is ok with your requirements):

*SwitchButtonComponent*:

```
<div class="container border rounded bg-white">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div *ngFor="let it of items" class="col" style="cursor:pointer;">
     <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="template" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: it }"></ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*AppComponent*:

```
<div>
  <switch-button [items]="[{path:'./img1.png'},{path:'./img2.png'}]">
    <ng-template let-item>
      <img-component [item]="item"></img-component>
    </ng-template>
  </switch-button>
</div>
```

*ImageComponent*:

```
<div>{{ item.path }}</div>

...

@Input()
item: any;
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lgl2la) is Stackblitz example demonstrating this.

Hope this helps.